# How to align quotation mark character (PIL image)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I've made a script which makes images out of any entered text like this:[image]

As you can see, the closing quotation mark looks nicely aligned. But if i enter any other text, it looks like this:[image]
As far as i know, it happens because of **not** monospace font.
Here you can see a part of my code:

```
    draw.text((150, offset), "«", font=fnt2, fill=(255,191,0)) #opening quotation mark
    for element in text_array:
        for line in textwrap.wrap(element, width = 32):
            draw.text((230, offset), line, font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255))
            last_line_len = len(line) #length of the last line of text
            offset += fnt.getsize(line)[1]
    print(last_line_len)
    draw.text((80 * last_line_len, offset-200), "»", font=fnt2, fill=(255,191,0)) #closing quotation mark
```

I need these quotation marks to be yellow and bold, so i'm using another font and different code lines to make it possible to realize.
And here you can look at the full code: https://pastebin.com/qP2ekvg9

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking and i did it! The only thing i had to do was find the length of the last line in pixels. Here is the changes i've made:

```
    for element in text_array:
        for line in textwrap.wrap(element, width = 32):
            draw.text((230, offset), line, font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255))
            last_line_len = fnt.getsize(line)[0]
            offset += fnt.getsize(line)[1]
    draw.text((230+ last_line_len, offset - 200), "»", font=fnt2, fill=(255,191,0)) #closing quotation mark
```